# Display all line numbers for user names starting with "admin" from passwd file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How do I find all the occurance of a particular text in a file with a shell script. (Not using grep command)

Answer (score 0):

awk  '/^admin/ {print NR;}' /etc/passwd

Comment: Strictly speaking, changing `admin` to `admin:x` here still could but shouldn't find a match. OP asked for (just) "user names starting with …". (I ran into this myself…)

Comment: I thought of dividing fields on ':' but the awk answer won't be accepted anyway.  Which is funny, since awk is much smaller, more efficient and better suited than bash.

Answer (score 0):

A POSIX shell-only solution could be

```sh
n=0
while n=$((n+1)); IFS=':' read -r u _
do
  case "$u" in
    admin*) echo $n;;
  esac
done < /etc/passwd
```